# How to change the cell value of grid view on click event of check box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to change the cell value on click event of check box

My Mark up code for grid view look like :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
AutoGenerateEditButton="True" Height="144px" 
Width="397px"
 onrowcommand="gvDetails_RowCommand" 
 onrowcancelingedit="gvDetails_RowCancelingEdit1" 
 onrowediting="gvDetails_RowEditing" onrowupdating="gvDetails_RowUpdating" 
 onrowdatabound="gvDetails_RowDataBound">
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
 <Columns>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Call">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCall" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  OnCheckedChanged="chkCall_CheckedChanged" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0033CC" />
  </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="caLLTIME" >
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0033CC" />
 </asp:BoundField>

 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

My C# coding :

```
protected void chkCall_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)sender).NamingContainer;      
    row.Cells[2].Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
}
```

Bu I am getting this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox' to
type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'
```

in the first line.

Please help me

Comment: Read the exception message. `sender` is a `Checkbox` type, so cast it as `Checkbox` instead of `Button`

Answer (score 1):

since sender is `CheckBox` you can cast it to `CheckBox` and then get the `NamingContainer`

```
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((CheckBox)sender).NamingContainer;
```